# First person camera acting weird in editor and in game

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

While I'm learning unity and C#, I made a first person controller using the new unity input system.

I scripted a first person camera, when I go in playmode in the editor, sometimes the camera works well, but sometimes it will stutter very hard when I move the mouse (the problem don't seem to appear with a controller), and I have no idea why it happens.

In the "built" version, the mouse sensitivity is very, very high and the controller sensitivity is very low (same in editor), but there is no stuttering at all.

So, do you have any ideas to fix it ?

Here is the piece of code (called in a LateUpdate loop)

```
private void MoveCamera()
{
    Vector2 MouseAxis = m_inputManager.GetMouseDelta();

    float MouseX = MouseAxis.x * CameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; 
    float MouseY = MouseAxis.y * CameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRot -= MouseY;
    xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, MinClamp, MaxClamp);

    m_camHolder.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0f, 0f);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * MouseX);
}
```

Comment: Just in general I don't think you need the `Time.deltaTime` here since the mouse delta already is the delta regarding the last frame so this is already frame-rate independent